# Unable To Run Sample Intern Automation Test

Tags: javascript, automation, intern

I tried to run simple Intern automation test sample like below:

```
define([
    'intern!object',
    'intern/chai!assert',
    'require'
], function (registerSuite, assert, require) {
    registerSuite({
        name: 'index',

        'Greeting': function () {
            return this.remote
                .get(require.toUrl('index.html'))
                .setFindTimeout(5000)
                .findByCssSelector('body.loaded')
                .findById('nameField')
                    .click()
                    .type('Elaine')
                    .end()
                .findByCssSelector('#loginForm input[type=submit]')
                    .click()
                    .end()
                .findById('greeting')
                .getVisibleText()
                .then(function (text) {
                    assert.strictEqual(text, 'Hello, ElaineqW!', 'Greeting should be displayed when the form is submitted');
                });
        }
    });
});
```

This should just be a simple thing to do. However, I face an issue when I tried to run the config through command line.

[image: Cannot call method get null]

Below is snippet of my config:

```
// Non-functional test suite(s) to run in each browser
    suites: [ 'C:/internKE/tests/functional/index' ],

    // Functional test suite(s) to run in each browser once non-functional tests are completed
    functionalSuites: [ 'C:/internKE/tests/functional/index' ],
```

I wonder what I do wrong so that the test wont be compiled.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot load functional tests into the unit testing system. Note the comment in the code you pasted that says “non-functional”. There is no `this.remote` in non-functional tests.

Also, please take care to note that module IDs are *not filesystem paths*.

Your configuration should be:

```
// Non-functional test suite(s) to run in each browser
suites: [],

// Functional test suite(s) to run in each browser once non-functional tests are completed
functionalSuites: [ 'tests/functional/index' ],
```

Comment: Thanks, I manage to get it run now, however, it seems to only return the test as 0/0 tests failed.

I intentionally make the wrong scenario on the test yet it still yield the same reuslt. Thanks